# How to find Base CPU Time and Memory-Stall Time

Tags: computer-architecture, cache

The program described below runs on a multiple issue processor with a 3-level CPU cache, a 4 GHz clock frequency, and the following performance metrics:

|  | Miss Penalty R/W | Data Miss Rate | Instruction Miss Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L1 Cache | 2 | 5% | 2% |
| L2 Cache | 5 | 2% | 1.3% |
| Main Memory | 100 | 0.3% | 1% |

with

| Instruction Class | Instruction Count | IPC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Branch/Jump | 2x10^5 | 1.1 |
| Load/Store | 4.1x10^4 | 0.9 |
| Arithmetic | 3.6 x10^6 | 1.5 |
| Float Add | 5.5x10^5 | 0.25 |

*IPC is given instead of CPI because of multiple issue*

### What is the base CPU time of the program? And what is the amount of time consumed by memory-stall clock cycles?

My attempt to answer this has been:

For Base CPU Time, I am using the following formula:

CPU Time = instruction count / IPC * T_clk

for each instruction count, so

Base CPU Time = (2x10^5/1.1 x 0.25) + ... + (5.5x10^5/0.25 x 0.25)

and for memory-stall clock cycle I am calculating

The number of stalls (miss cycles) per instruction can be treated as a portion of CPI. To get this value in terms of time, multiply this rate by the clock period:

MST = summation (miss rate_i x miss penalty_i) x T_clk x Instruction count

where i is the instruction class. Memory stall cycles/times are always subdivided into Data and Instruction. So the total MST is equal to MST_data + MST_instruction.

Is this the correct approach? I have doubts since I am using all the instructions to calculate the MST of the caches and main memory, and I don't know how to split it. I also am not sure if I should be using all the instructions to calculate the Base CPU Time, since part of those instructions contribute to the miss rate.